# jqgrid populating data, but giving tr an ID of null

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Ok, so my jqgrid is populating the data fine, and also hiding columns I need to. However now search isn't working, and, when inspecting the `<tr>` of each row of data, I see they all have an id of null:

http://sysport.co.uk/admin/grid/TEST.php

Now search doesn't work and export to excel only gives the same rows repeated.

Below is my code for the jqGrid:

sysport.co.uk/admin/grid/37multiple.js (Too big to post on here).

Any help would be massively appreciated, never got an answer on the forum.

Comment: Quite a few of your posts refer to offsite locations. Please try to not do this. Because these are test pages, when you tear them down these questions lose their usefulness. Remember, SO is a repository of questions and answers to benefit not just you, but also the larger community and future users. Broken links help no-one. Please provide sample code snippets in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the response from the server. Each row *does* have an id of null there.

Comment: ok, solved that problem... however it was in fact something I believed would solve a higher problem.. the search doesnt work! It did work until a couple of days ago... but now the box wont come up as it's supposed to:  http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html ("New in version 3.7 " > "Multiple Search" left hand menu)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the response of the server you will see this:

```
{"page":"1","total":1,"records":"366","rows":[{"id":null,"cell":["4","Borough of Barnsley Swimming Club"
```

The ID = null. I dont know how you create the jsonstring. So look into that function and fill the 'ID' with the right value.

If the ID is the same as the ID in the first column you can do this to:
Alter the settings of the jsonreader in the jqgridsettings to this:

```
jsonReader: { cell: "", id: "0" },
rowNum:50,
rowTotal: 2000,
rowList : [30,50,100],
...
```

With these settings, the jsonreader will know that the first columns is your ID column. 
Then you can return your jsontring in like this:

```
{"page":"1","total":1,"records":"366","rows":[["4","Borough of Barnsley Swimming Club"...
```

I don't know if this ID problem is the root of the problem for your excel and search problem. But maybe if the ID is filled in, it will work...

For more inforamation about the jsonreader, taak a look [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data&s%5b%5d=jsonreader#json_data)

Comment: Hi bruno, The excel problem isnt, I removed it for testing. I now have the ID pulling through but the search still doesnt work ( see above response to abestos). Cheers aswell!